# Create categorical bar chart in plotly that handles string values for x?

Tags: javascript, plotly, data-visualization

I would like to create a bar chart using plotly JavaScript with five bars labeled `['2', 'hello', '5', '9', '6']` with monotonically increasing values (just for sanity check) of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I thought the following would work, but it is doing something clever under the hood to interpret x values as numbers and dropping non-numerical strings like 'hello'. Perhaps there is just another plot type I am supposed to be using?

```
Plotly.newPlot('plot3', [{x: ['2', 'hello', '5', '9', '6'], y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], type: 'bar'}]);
```

Well, interestingly you can see exactly what I want when none of the x values can be interpreted as string.

```
Plotly.newPlot('plot3', [{x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], type: 'bar'}]);
```

Oh my, so for now I will use the following hack that makes my skin crawl.

```
Plotly.newPlot('plot3', [{x: ['&nbsp;2&nbsp;', '&nbsp;1&nbsp;', '&nbsp;5&nbsp;', '&nbsp;9&nbsp;', '&nbsp;6&nbsp;'], y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], type: 'bar'}]);
```

Comment: After some quick testing/look on their website, I don't think you can pass a string and integer at the same time. If a sting is added in a mix on integers then it defaults to plotting the integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a layout option for xaxis called type that will force data to be treated as categorical. I found it in deep in [the plotly javascript docs](https://plotly.com/javascript/axes/#categorical-axes)

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category'
  }
}
```